# Displaying Content only when ListViewItem is Selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have a `ListBox` when one of the `ListBoxItems` are selected I want to change the visibility of the button "View" and display it. Meaning that the default state is Hidden.

Is this possible and if so, do I solve this with a trigger in XAML or in code behind?

**XAML Piece**

```
<ListBox Background="Transparent" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Beige" Margin="10 10 10 10" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Height="100"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Name="TopRow" Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Name="BottomRow" Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="LeftSideMenu" Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Name="Middle" Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding name}" />

                <Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="view" Click="viewClicked_Click"
                    Grid.Row="0">View</Button>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Content="{Binding description}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Old useless code]

---

EDIT:
Well I didn't read the question good enough but this should do the trick:
Replace the button in your `DataTemplate` with this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="view" Click="viewClicked_Click"
        Content="View">
 <Button.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" 
                 Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

What happends here is that the style sets the Visibility property to Collapsed and uses a trigger to change that. I've used a `DataTrigger` so you can use the `{Binding ...}`.
With the `{Binding RelativeSource={..}}` you can look for an Ancestor, here we are looking for an Ancestor of type `ListBoxItem`.

What this does is look 'up' in the WPF tree to see if this button has a Parent object which is of type `ListBoxItem` if it's found it will check the IsSelected (`Path=IsSelected`) property if it's True and will then update the Visibility Property of the button.

I hope this explanation makes sense! :-)

---

EDIT2:
Just for fun, the code behind way:

```
private Button _previousButton;
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 if (_previousButton != null)
  _previousButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

 // Make sure an item is selected
 if (listBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
  return;

 // Get the first SelectedItem (use a List<object> when 
 // the SelectionMode is set to Multiple)
 object selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItems[0];
 // Get the ListBoxItem from the ContainerGenerator
 ListBoxItem listBoxItem = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
 if (listBoxItem == null)
  return;

 // Find a button in the WPF Tree
 Button button = FindDescendant<Button>(listBoxItem);
 if (button == null)
  return;

 button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
 _previousButton = button;
}

/// <summary>
/// Finds the descendant of a dependency object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T FindDescendant<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
 // Check if this object is the specified type
 if (obj is T)
  return obj as T;

 // Check for children
 int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
 if (childrenCount < 1)
  return null;

 // First check all the children
 for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
 {
  DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
  if (child is T)
   return child as T;
 }

 // Then check the childrens children
 for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
 {
  DependencyObject child = FindDescendant<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i));
  if (child != null && child is T)
   return child as T;
 }

 return null;
}
```

I suggest you use the XAML Trigger "way" because it's much cleaner...

Comment: This displays ALL buttons, for each item. The button is in each element. So your answer is wrong :/

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. But you are missing the point. The Buttons are REPEATED inside the ListBox. Each ListBoxItem consists of a StackPanel. See my example please. Your example works if you want to display ONE button NOT in the List.

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick. Care to elaborate on what you really did there? Maybe point out a good explenation of these types of bindings?

Comment: I hope I made sense in my explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter on the selected item on the list to determine the visibility.

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}" />
```

Here is the value converter

```
public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to check if the SelectedItem is the same as the ListBoxItem the button is in...

Comment: Yah, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MVVM pattern, you should bind your button to an ICommand such as the DelegateCommand from the [MVVM Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit). That way the button will use the command's CanExecute() state to decide for itself whether it should be enabled or not.